# Failed to create crx file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ubuntu-18.04, crx

I'm trying to create crx file with the following command on a Virtual machine.

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --pack-extension=/tmp/private/1584732592206 --pack-extension-key=/tmp/private/ibehccbjeaejbaaamkdnaogceilbogkg.pem
```

I'm getting the following error:
**ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1512)] Unable to open X display.**

Other details:
OS: **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)**
Chrome Version: **Google Chrome 80.0.3987.132**

Can you please guide me overcome this issue? I just want to create crx file with the chrome executable.

Comment: I don't know what this error is but are you sure you need a to create a .crx? You don't need that to publish to the Webstore and you can't install them manually either for a while now.

Comment: I dont want to use google chrome web store. I want to put this crx file into my own server(private chrome strore)

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think you can install it like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11879334/3862289